# Where to put a mezuzah if there's no doorpost on the outside of the door?

Tags: halacha, mezuzah

There is a tiny doorpost on the inside of the door but there's not enough room for a slanted placement.  On the outside the door is flush with the wall so there is no doorpost to place it on at all, even vertically.

Similar to these doors:

[image: these doors]

Comment: Can it be posted while standing upright?

Comment: @chachamNisan on the outside the door is flush with the wall

Answer (score 5):

It is important to ask these questions to a [rabbi](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146), and to send pictures if asking remotely, as small details can have important consequences.

In general, if there is no space on the doorpost, one can drill into it (and I saw new appartments in Israel where every mezuza was drilled into the doorposts - some prefer it this way halachically).

OU [writes](https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/mezuza-part-2/)

> Place the mezuza outside the door but within the door frame. If not
>   possible, you may place the mezuza inside the door frame.
>
> Note: You may recess a mezuza into the door frame.

TorahTots [writes](http://www.torahtots.com/mezuza/howandwheretoplacethemezuza.pdf)

> In extenuating circumstances, such as the aforementioned examples, it
>   would be preferred to drill a hole, less than a handbreadth deep, into
>   the doorpost and place the mezuza into the groove.
>
> If that is not possible, then it would be permitted to affix the
>   mezuza behind the door provided it was placed on the doorpost under
>   the lintel. [see picture on top of p. 4]

Comment: See the photo in the link edited into question. יפה כתבת

Comment: I can't visualize these places in your answer: 1) "... If there is no space on the doorpost one can drill into it..." 2) OU writes: "it's not possible you may place the mezuzah inside the door frame you may recess a mezuzah into the door frame." 3) "it would be preferred to drill a hole...into the doorpost...into the groove." 4) "afix the mezuzah behind the door provided it was placed on the doorpost under the lintel."

Comment: @larry909 the first three places are INTO the doorpost if there is space to drill a hole for the mezuza into its width or depth. If this is not possible see the drawing on top of page 4 of the TorahTots link (apologies I had originally forgotten the link but corrected it now). See [here](http://www.torahtots.com/mezuza/howandwheretoplacethemezuza.pdf)

Comment: @mbloch you mean on the outside, even if it's not a recessed doorpost as in the photo in my post? So the mizuzah will be facing outside.

Comment: @larry909 the second opinion from TorahTors is indeed on the outside, did you see their drawing (figure 3, top of p. 4)?

Comment: @larry909 for examples of mezuzot drilled into the doorpost, see [here](https://vanishedworld.blog/2013/02/09/scars-on-the-door-frame/) (although angle is at times exaggerated)